# Check if modelitem refers to currently logged in user with mvc identity

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC in order to generate a couple of views within my webpage. For a way of logging in, I've decided to use Asp.net's Identity, which I am very happy with.

However, I'm trying to find an efficient/ 'normal' way of testing if the user is logged in, and are looking at info that refers to them.

As a test, I found that:

```
 if (User.Identity.Name == (Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email).ToString()))
        {
            <div>THIS IS ME</div>
        }
```

razor code works for this.

However, this seems quite inefficient, and I was wondering if there is a more appropriate way of telling 'is this their row in which they can edit'.

Comment: Is this in a loop? What's `item`?

Answer (score 1):

I would add the logic in the controller

```
 public ActionResult(){
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    List<ApplicationUser> model = db.Users.ToList();

    // Viewbag just being an example for a model. It would be better to 
    // pass this into a property in the model that is being passed to the view. 
    foreach (var item in model)
    {
        ViewBag.UserEmail = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name 
                         == item.Email ? item.Email : null;
    }
  // If we were returning a viewmodel we could add this check into a
  // ApplicationUser ( public ApplicationUser AppUser {get; set;}) 
  // property which could then be accessed in the model as Model.AppUser. This 
  // would hold all the values for the application user. If that is           
  // something you would need 


 return View(model);
 }
```

This will assign the `ViewBag.UserEmail` to either the currently logged in users email or null. I added the full namespace because sometimes `Current` is not directly accessible

And in the view

```
 if(Viewbag.UserEmail != null)
 {
    <div> THIS IS ME</div>
 }
```

This then just checks if the ViewBag is null and displays a code block if it is not.

This will still work in a loop. Because the ViewBag holds the current users email which can be checked against in a foreach

```
@foreach ( var item in Model){

       <h4>@item.Name</h4>

       if(ViewBag.UserEmail == item.Email){
          <button>Edit </button> // Should only be visible to logged in user 
       }

       // Or Like
        @( ViewBag.User == item.Email ? 
          Html.Raw("<button class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</button>") :    
          Html.Raw("<button class='btn btn-primary'>View</button>"))
}
```